# When attempting to access the UEFI firmware settings, screen goes black (ROG STRIX Z370 G-GAMING)

Tags: uefi, resolution, intel

I'm using a dual-boot setup configuration with RAID 0 as storage only. My system configuration is as follows:

Motherboard: ROG Strix Z370-G Gaming
CPU: I5-9400F (no integrated graphics)
GPU GTX 1660TI (Asus)
SSD: PNY 480GB to dual-boot
SSD: Sandisk 240GB as storage
HDD: WD 1TB as secundary storage
Monitor 1: AOC 24' IPC 1080p - HDMI-DisplayPort
Monitor 2: Acer 21' VA 1080p - HDMI

My PC is working fine and performs all tasks without any issues. However, when I attempt to access the UEFI firmware settings using F2 or Del, the screen goes black, and I'm unable to access the UEFI firmware settings at all.

I already tried to access the UEFI firmware settings with only one monitor, cleared CMOS.

Comment: This will sound strange, but humour me. Disconnect your mouse and try (I have a mouse that prevents me from going into BIOS!!!) Also, did you try each monitor individually, in every port?

Comment: If you can get into the BIOS with a simpler monitor set and/or no mouse, that sounds like a bug in your BIOS, or perhaps poor compatibility with your graphics card.  You could report that to ASUS.  They might not be as interested in fixing bugs and incompatibilities in the BIOS on that vs. a latest-generation motherboard, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I've seen that the motherboard itself also has a graphics port and that BIOS is displayed there. It may be displaying with a weird resolution that the monitor can't handle though.

Comment: @LPChip - no amount of on-board graphics port hardware will majick a display out of and `I5-9400F` :p

Comment: If you run windows ... does `shutdown -r -fw -f -t 0` (in an elevated command prompt) get you into BIOS? In Linux, it'd be `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` as root (or sudo)

Comment: @Bravo I've seen motherboards with an onboard graphics chip just for the BIOS, as backup. Never underestimate the unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've connected a monitor to the bottommost video connector on the 1660 - that's the one used for BIOS/UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the connections like you said, but I didn't see any changes. Anyway, a few days ago, while cleaning my room, I accidentally pressed a key and it worked, the UEFI firmware settings appeared.

Before you ask, I know the keys to enter the BIOS and other functions on my PC:

**F8 - Boot Menu** ||
**DEL / F2 - BIOS menu**

Before that accident they weren't working, now everyone is working!

Comment: Important information!

In the meantime, **Nvidia has released some updates.**

I don't know how, exactly, **but it's possible** that from one of these updates the BIOS **started to consider the GPU before "boot".**